# Concatenating Arbitrary number of items of a string in Python

Tags: python

Given a list `['a','b','c','d','e','f']`.No. of divisions to be made 2.. So In the first string i want to take the 0,2,4 elements of the list, and then concatenate them separated by a space delimiter with the second string of 1,3,5 elements.
The output needs to be in the form of `k = ["a c e", "b d f"]`

The actual program is to take in a string (eg {ball,bat,doll,choclate,bat,kite}), also take in the input of the number of kids who take those gifts(eg 2), and then divide them so that the frst kid gets a gift, goes to the back of the line, the second kid takes the gift and stands at the back, in that way all kids take gifts. If gifts remain then the first kid again takes a gift and the cycle continues....
desired output for above eg: {"ball doll bat" , "bat choclate kite"}

Comment: clean up your second paragraph and be more specific

Comment: What do you mean by "list in a string"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a general way to do this for any number of groups:

```
def merge(lst, ngroups):
    return [' '.join(lst[start::ngroups]) for start in xrange(ngroups)]
```

Here is how it's used:

```
>>> lst = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
>>> merge(lst, 2)
['a c e', 'b d f']

>>> merge(lst, 3)
['a d', 'b e', 'c f']
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your generalised answer.. Would be a great hep to me :)

Comment: @FirstRock: This means that you haven't executed the `def merge(lst, ngroups): ...` block at the top of my answer.

Comment: Hey..! Got that.. And its working amazing.. Before moving on to python I tried to code it in C and java but concatenation and all was all getting a little too deep.. In python concise and incredible. I m loving it..

Answer (score 6):

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

k = [" ".join(lst[::2]), " ".join(lst[1::2])]
```

output:

```
['a c e', 'b d f']
```

more generic solution:

```
def group(lst, n):
    return [" ".join(lst[i::n]) for i in xrange(n)]

lst = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
print group(lst, 3)
```

output:

```
['a d', 'b e', 'c f']
```

Comment: +1 Not sure what the 2nd paragraph means but this is perfect so far. You should change `l` to `L` as stated in PEP-8.

Comment: i don't like capital letters for variables, so let's use `lst` instead... :)

Comment: @mata Thank You for your revised generalised answer. very helpful :)